# std::search itterating over PAGE_NOACCESS region crash

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a function which utilizes std::search to find a pattern of bytes within a memory range using a DLL. The function works correctly as it utilizes my pattern class which essentially holds a vector of bytes and searches for it within a given memory range. However, when using the function on a program which protects the code section with PAGE_NOACCESS privileges. I receive crashes. I've attempted a work around by testing the memory being read with VirtualQuery to no success as the code still crashes.

```
 std::pair< uintptr_t, uintptr_t > get_region_dimensions( uintptr_t addr ) {
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    if( !VirtualQuery( ( LPCVOID ) addr, &mbi, sizeof( mbi ) ) )
        return {};

    return std::pair< uintptr_t, uintptr_t >{ ( uintptr_t ) mbi.AllocationBase, ( uintptr_t ) mbi.AllocationBase + mbi.RegionSize };
 }

 NOINLINE bool is_valid_ptr( uintptr_t addr ) {
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    constexpr uint32_t BAD_MASK = ( PAGE_NOACCESS | PAGE_GUARD );

    if( !VirtualQuery( ( LPCVOID ) addr, &mbi, sizeof( mbi ) ) )
        return false;

    if( ( mbi.Protect & BAD_MASK ) )
        return false;

    return true;
}

 // lambda inside a different function.
 const auto address = std::search( start, end, pattern.cbegin(), pattern.cend(),
        []( const uint8_t &a, const memory::byte &b ) { 
            // retrive address of the byte we are looking at.
            const auto data = &a;

            // get dimensions and page validity using VirtualQuery
            static auto region_dimensions = Utils::get_region_dimensions( data );
            static auto valid             = Utils::is_valid_ptr( data );

            // have we exceeded the page with known protection rights
            // we don't want to call VirtualQuery on every byte of the scan
            if( ( uintptr_t ) data > region_dimensions.second ) {
                region_dimensions = Utils::get_region_dimensions( data );
                valid             = Utils::is_valid_ptr( data );
            }

            // if the page isn't valid and we don't have read privileges skip the byte and ret false
            if( !valid )
                return false;

            return b.compare( a );
        }
    );
```

Addition:

The code works correctly then using VirtualQuery on every single address of each byte (this is too slow though).

```
 // lambda inside a different function.
 const auto address = std::search( start, end, pattern.cbegin(), pattern.cend(),
    []( const uint8_t &a, const memory::byte &b ) { 
        // retrive address of the byte we are looking at.
        const auto data = &a;

        if( !Utils::is_valid_ptr( data ) )
            return false;

        return b.compare( a );
    }
);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205267/discussion-on-question-by-john-james-stdsearch-itterating-over-page-noaccess-r).

Answer (score 1):

at first is wrong too - call `VirtualQuery` on single address 2 time inside `is_valid_ptr` and `get_region_dimensions` - error. so must be single function, which call `VirtualQuery` on address only once.

at second - both functions - `is_valid_ptr` and `get_region_dimensions` also is wrong implemented.

after `VirtualQuery` return - first what we must do - check **State** - because for **MEM_FREE**

> the information in the **AllocationBase**, **AllocationProtect**,
>   **Protect**, and **Type** members is undefined.

for **MEM_RESERVE** -

> information in the **Protect** member is undefined.

so check `mbi.Protect` we can only in case `mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT`

then `mbi.AllocationBase + mbi.RegionSize` - always wrong. the `RegionSize` is size from `BaseAddress` but not from `AllocationBase` (which also undefined in case `MEM_FREE`)

example of correct usage of `VirtualQuery` - dump all process virtual space

```
VOID DumpVmap()
{
    PVOID AllocationBase = 0;
    ::MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    for (; VirtualQuery(mbi.BaseAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)); (PBYTE&)mbi.BaseAddress += mbi.RegionSize)
    {
        if (mbi.State == MEM_FREE) continue;

        if (AllocationBase != mbi.AllocationBase)
        {
            if (AllocationBase)
            {
                DbgPrint("</%p>\n", AllocationBase);
            }

            AllocationBase = mbi.AllocationBase;

            DbgPrint("<%p>\n", AllocationBase);
        }

        switch (mbi.State)
        {
        case MEM_COMMIT:
            DbgPrint("\t[%p, %p) %x %x\n", mbi.BaseAddress, (PBYTE)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize, mbi.Type, mbi.Protect);
            break;
        case MEM_RESERVE:
            DbgPrint("\t[%p, %p) %x\n", mbi.BaseAddress, (PBYTE)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize, mbi.Type);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (AllocationBase)
    {
        DbgPrint("</%p>\n", AllocationBase);
    }
}
```

note also, that because you not own allocations - after you get information about some memory region - it can changed. with a small probability but maybe. because this - you need scan inside __try/__except block (or handle exceptions in another way). try suspend process (all threads in process except your) - no sense. at first this is anyway not 100% solution, because another process still can change virtual memory in target process. we need really "lock" virtual memory map instead "suspend" threads (in all system ?!) but no api for this (like we can lock heap). so normal solution - handle possible (with very low probability) exceptions

Comment: @JohnJames and what exactly do you disagree with ?